# Is whow a word?

Tags: etymology

According to this chart describing an extension of 5W1H, the word *how* originates from the word *whow* which means “how much”.

I can’t find any references to such a word on the Internet. Is (or was) *whow* really a word? If not, where do you think the author of the chart got his information from?

Here is the chart (Japanese only): <http://homepage2.nifty.com/thinking-way-8W1H/8W1H(A4).pdf>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is (or was) “whow” really a word?

Certainly.  For this they invented dictionaries, one of the best of which for finding out whether something once was a word is the OED:

> **whou, whough(e, whouh, whow(e,** variants of **how, howe** *int.<sup>1</sup>*
>
> - C. 1425 Quhow: see **whew** *int*.
> - 1542 Udall *Erasm. Apoph*. 314 ― Whough, saieth he, half my brothers bodye is more then the whole.
> - 1598 R. Bernard tr. *Terence, Phormio* ɪɪɪ. iii, ― How much money need you? speake. But thirtie poundes. Thirtie! Whow.
> - 1615 Brathwait *Strappado* 129 ― Whou Billie whou, what faire has thou bin at?
> - 1627 W. Hawkins *Apollo Shroving* ɪɪ. iv. 33 ― He answered me nothing but whough, pugh.
> - 1815 Scott *Guy M.* xlv, ― ‘Eh whow! Eh whow!’ ejaculated the honest farmer, as he looked round upon his friend’s miserable apartment.
>
> So  **† whowb(e** (in quots. as *sb*.; cf. **howbub, hubbub**).
>
> - 1600 W. Watson *Decacordon* ᴠɪɪ. x. (1602) 217 ― They hissed him out with whoubs & hoo-bubs.
> - 1600 W. Watson *Decacordon* ɪx. viii. 327 [see **how, howe** *int.<sup>1</sup>*].

It used to be a word.  It probably isn’t any longer: modulo the cited farmer’s ejaculation, it hasn’t been much seen in four centuries. It used to mean the same thing as did the word ***How!*** when uttered as an interjection.

Comment: Whow! Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like you need an OED subscription to find that entry! I should probably get one. So "whow" definitely was a word. However, it appears that the definition of "how much" is incorrect. What do you think? Does the use of "whow" as an interjection as you described imply the meaning of how much? Is there another good source out there that can speak into that?

Comment: @David: UK residents can get a free subscription through a public library.

Comment: Very surprising. I would've bet it was some newfangled word, not something five centuries old – and I would have lost my money.  Normally, I find "is this a real word" questions candidates for downvotes, but I'll certainly make an exception in this case, where it's been dropped from most [dictionaries](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/spellcheck/british/?q=whow), and the answer [isn't so easily found](http://onelook.com/?w=whow&ls=a).

Comment: Fascinating answer +1. Surely the exclamation "wow!" comes from "whow."

Comment: @BarrieEngland How nifty! Unfortunately though I am a UK citizen, I reside in Japan. I'll just have to ask my relatives to look things up for me :)

Comment: @J.R. Thanks for the onelook.com link! That's a useful tool I didn't know about.

Comment: Can anybody offer a definition? I've yet to find one...

Comment: @David: Many college libraries subscribe to the OED, too, so you might be able to get access from a campus. As for the meaning of _whow_, it essentially means the same as _how_, near as I can tell (the OED redirects to the entry for _how_,  then cites a few instances of it). 500-1000 yrs ago, there were quite a few different ways to spell _how_; perhaps the more interesting question is, quhow in the world did a modern pub – i.e., the one you linked to – end up with _whow_ in that matrix? (Yes, _quhow_ was one way to spell _how_ in the 1500s; wish I could use it in Scrabble, but I'm dubious).

Comment: Thanks @J.R.! Your comment inspired me and I did some more digging and found the answer to your more interesting question. The author explains in homepage2.nifty.com/thinking-way-8W1H/mmdl/5.3whow.htm that while staring at the matrix he wondered why all of the words began with "wh" except for "how". After researching with no luck he happened upon an old bookstore in Tokyo and randomly pulled out W. W. Skeat's "An Etymological Dictionary of the English Language" (ca. 1800's) and found that the entry for how says "also: whow". He then also discovered the same entry in the OED mentioned above.

Comment: @J.R. as for the definition of whow, I suppose it is safer to say that it is more of a synonym and parent of how than a word with a distinct meaning of "how much". Let me know if you disagree.

Comment: @David: I agree, and I think this question has become even more interesting with that background information.